# PHP: Output is always buffered when script is loaded via jQuery .load() method

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to output echo statements in my PHP script which when launched normally via browser works fine. But when the PHP page is loaded via jQuery .load() method, the output is **always** buffered irrespective of whatever I do.

PHP (test.php)

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Surrogate-Control: BigPipe/1.0');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');

ob_end_flush();
ob_implicit_flush();

echo "First line<br>";
sleep(5);
echo "Second line<br>";
```

So, when I launch test.php in my browser, I get the first line followed by the second line after 5 seconds (as expected). However, when I load this script into another HTML in a `<div>` tag, both the `echo` statements output at the same time i.e. after 5 seconds. Browser Chrome 64.0.3282.186.

HTML:

```
<div id="testDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $("#testDiv").load("test.php");
</script>
```

Comment: PHP's output is the same in both scenarios. I'd say the `jquery` is the one causing this - by **waiting** for the complete result. But what do you think should happen instead? Do you expect the first call of `load()` to show the first line and the second call - after a while - to show both lines? ... _or what exactly do you expect?_

Comment: Anyway, here's an answer that might help you out a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42839768/1285669

Comment: @Smuuf I'm only loading the PHP script once. The expected output is the first `echo` prints the first line of text in the `<div>` in which it is loaded, and then after 5 seconds delay print the second line of text. Yes, jQuery's `load()` method somehow is waiting for the entire output to be received to flush the output into the `<div>` in which the PHP script is loaded. Any idea how to tell jQuery load() method to display the content as and when received instead of buffering it?

Comment: Hi. What is the main purpose of this scenario? Are you trying to create an animated HTML? Use javascript directly, not php. Or are you trying to show progress of a server script? Use javascript to call the server every x seconds to check the progress.

Comment: @verjas I'm trying to show progress from a rather complicated PHP script. Polling the PHP every x seconds, doesn't seem a good idea as I will be dealing with close to 800,000 records which are being processed by the PHP script in different scenarios. I'd rather `echo` the status as and when certain milestones are achieved in the PHP.

Comment: How about this: the "complicated.php" file stores it's progress in a txt file (instead of echo). The javascript loads that file every x seconds to see if the content changed (or calls a different php file to check if the file changed). When the content changes, the javascript changes the html in the current page.

Comment: Or use js [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) instead of jquery load?

Comment: @verjas : Thanks. EventSource seems like the possible solution. I just downloaded the sample scripts and they work exactly in the scenario I have. Thank you very much! Please add that as a solution to the question.

Comment: Super! Good luck with it.

Comment: https://socket.io/ could also help you out.